# Can't upload audio file through server using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, audio, amazon-s3, alamofire

```
class VoiceRecogViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {


var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?
var error: NSError?
var soundFileURL: URL?
var soundFilePath: String = ""
var data : NSData?

@IBOutlet weak var startRocordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var stopRecordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playRecordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var continueButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    playRecordButton.isEnabled = false
    stopRecordButton.isEnabled = false

    let dirPaths =
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,
                                            .userDomainMask, true)

    let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
    soundFilePath = (docsDir as NSString).appendingPathComponent("sound.wav")
    soundFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)

    let recordSettings = [AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.min.rawValue,
                          AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16,
                          AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                          AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0] as [String : Any]

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [])
    try! audioSession.setActive(true)

    if let err = error {
        print("audioSession error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
    }

    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: soundFileURL!,
                                            settings: recordSettings as [String : AnyObject])
    } catch {
        audioRecorder = nil
    }

    audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func startRecord(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if audioRecorder?.isRecording == false {
        playRecordButton.isEnabled = false
        startRocordButton.isEnabled = false
        stopRecordButton.isEnabled = true
        audioRecorder?.record()
    }
}

@IBAction func stopRecord(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    stopRecordButton.isEnabled = false
    playRecordButton.isEnabled = true
    startRocordButton.isEnabled = true

    if audioRecorder?.isRecording == true {
        audioRecorder?.stop()
    } else {
        audioPlayer?.stop()
    }
}

@IBAction func playRecord(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if audioRecorder?.isRecording == false {
        stopRecordButton.isEnabled = true
        startRocordButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundFileURL!)
        audioPlayer?.delegate = self
        audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer?.play()
    } catch {
        print("audioPlayer error")
    }
}

@IBAction func continueRegist(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Token ___(**token**)_____",
                                "Accept": "application/json"]

    data = NSData (contentsOf: soundFileURL!)

    let parameters: Parameters = ["from_account_id": "3",
                                  "to_account_id": "4",
                                  "file": data!,
                                 ]

    let URL = "http://leaofımjpüsmfweüdıpckfw"

            Alamofire.request(URL, method: .put, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
                if let data = response.result.value {
                    print(data)
                }
            }
}
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    startRocordButton.isEnabled = true
    stopRecordButton.isEnabled = false
}

func audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, error: Error?) {
    print("Audio Play Decode Error")
}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
}

func audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, error: Error?) {
    print("Audio Record Encode Error")
}
```

I shared my code above. Here the point is recording audio as .wav, playing it in app and in continueRegist part I want to call put method with alamofire and upload the audio to our amazons3server. Recording and playing audio part is totally working. The problem is in the method continueRegist. After calling the method, I am getting the correct response, it looks successful. Then, I am checking it from the url of our s3 server. The audio seems like uploaded but when I download and play it, it is not working. I could not figure out the where problem is.

Also, when I try to upload from Postman with selecting file and giving the right form data information, I can listen the sound I uploaded to the s3 server. What might be wrong here?

Below you can find my request through Postman:

Body:
[image: body]

I forgot to choose the file when I am taking the screenshot but it is simply a .wav file.

Headers
[image: headers]

Please do not hesitate to ask me questions those does not satisfy you.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There is no error given. Both server and amazon s3 accept my request and put the file to s3. For some reasons I do not understand and believe the problem somewhere there, when I manually download the file from the s3 link, my file cannot be played. Please note I can play the audio file with downloading which I send via Postman. There might be a problem with constructing the body.

Comment: So the problem is when you download the audio not upload it since your able to play the audio through Postman

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a screen shot of your Postman

Comment: Yeah sure, right away, give me a sec

Comment: Edited @ELKA, you can see now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your Alamofire Request: You are building a JSON with the audio data in the JSON. However, you can check in Postman the HTTP code(top right/under send) that the request is Multi Part Form Data.

**How to implement a multipart Alamofire:**
It should be something similar to that I am not sure about `appendBodyPart` statements. They depend on your case

```
let audioData: NSData = ...//should be loaded from the file

Alamofire.Manager.upload(.PUT,
                          URL,
                          headers: headers,
                          multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "3".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), name: "from_account_id")
                            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "4".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), name: "to_account_id")
                            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: audioData, name: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
                            },
                          encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                            switch encodingResult {

                            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                                upload.responseJSON { response in

                                }

                            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                                // Error while encoding request:
                            }
})
```

Comment: Okay I will play with your suggestion a little and try to make it work, then will reply back. Much appreciated

Comment: Can you also add Authentication header to your answer as an example?

Comment: i am not on my Laptop.  the edit actually removed the header parameter. There should be a method which takes parameters the request type(.Post/.put..) and headers

Comment: Yeah well I tried a lot, according to your suggestions and from the Alamofire's official but could not make it work out properly. Felt like I am close to solution, but does not work.

Comment: Yeah you re very close: the http code in postman what does it say? Can you add a screenshot

Comment: Yeay did it work finally!! Much appreciated for the great advice. I only changed the mime type to audio/wav

Comment: Yeah that's what i was thinkiing of

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code to upload audio file:

```
let uploadAudioURL = "http://<your post API url>"



    let header : [String:String] = [
        "Authorization" : "<your authorisation token>"
    ]

    let voiceData = try? Data(contentsOf: <url of audio file to upload>)


    let params : [String:String] = [
        "length" : "39000",
        "title" : "Trying to upload",
    ]

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(voiceData!, withName: "voice", fileName: "TempRecordedAudioFile", mimeType: "audio/m4a")
            for (key, value) in params {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
    },
        usingThreshold : SessionManager.multipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
        to : uploadAudioURL,
        method: .post,
        headers: header){ (result) in

            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("Response : ",JSON)

                    }
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }

    }
```

Hopefully it will help.

Some points to note for using the above code snippet:

1. Ensure you provide your upload URL
2. Add needed authorisation header details.
3. In the Alamofire.upload statement ensure the `withName` is set to your upload API parameter name. I used `voice`, you might have different parameter name.
4. `upload.uploadProgress()` is optional. You can delete it if you don't need it.